# Unable to run jupyter notebook in a conda enviroment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to run jupyter notebook from a conda environment.

This is what I am doing

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
jupyter notebook
```

In this the browser open the page `http://localhost:8888/tree/` but if I try to open a notebook I get this message

[image]

and the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/html/conf.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the command prompt in the directory where you want to create your notebook by typing `cmd` in the address bar. This should help to avoid this error.

Comment: Are you assuming the OP is on `Windows` platform?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the permission of those files manually as [suggested on the nbconvert issue tracker](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1430#issuecomment-703076623). Go to `/usr/locall/share/jupyter/` and run the following

```sh
# change the permissions on the directories to group, other read and execute
$ find ./ -type d -exec chmod go+rx {} \;enter code here

# change all the other files to group, other read
$ find ./ -type f -exec chmod  go+r {} \;
    
# change all the executables to group, other execute
$ find ./ -type f -perm -100 -exec chmod go+x {} \;
```